# Filter within group properties from Parameter SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I am facing following problem:
I am using a report with several dataset in one table. The rows are filtered by parameters in the grupping of rows. I want to make the report more flexible and therefore filter the rowgroup based on a parameter, which I fetch in an Dataset, too. How can I refer to different Datasets or a parameter in the value property?
Or I thought maybe there is a statement (iif clause) that gives back 1 and zero and the problem is done.

I have tried something like this: (the filter expressions seems to have to many arguments, but I don't know how to refer directly so I used a formula...
=iif(cbool(Fields!Szenario.Value, "ReportMonth")=cbool(Fields!Szenario.Value),1,0)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter based on a parameter you would use an expression like this:

```
=IIf(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value = Fields!Szenario.Value, true, false)
```

The filter should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Hello Steven, I have tried this it is given the mistake: "rsFilterEvaluationError". Formula is like =IIf(Parameters!ScenarioScenario.Value = Fields!Szenario.Value, true, false) everything else as in your screen.

Comment: I just realized, that I forgot to underline: I am trying to filter in the Grupping of rows, I can not filter simply in the query. I want to slice with filtering in the grouping in the tablix.

Comment: You can filter groups in the same way as datasets. What is the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

Steven White, thanks for your help. Yesterday I tried it again in a different way, and it worked. Here it is:

=IIF(Fields!Szenario.value=Parameters!SelectForecast.label,1,0) as Expression, 
beeing an Integer = the Value of 1.

Kind of confussing that the it has to be Value=Label. But once again showing the result of the expressing in textboxes did the trick.